# Segmentation in OTB gives blank rectangle as output

Tags: qgis, image-segmentation, otb-applications

I am trying to segment a raster image to get a vector output. I am using OTB 6.6.1 in QGIS 3.4. In the segmentation window, I selected the input raster which is a 3 band (true colour) sentinel 2 image and chose the **meanshift** under **segmentation algorithm** and chose an output file name with .shp as output. I left all the other options to default. I am getting the output as a blank rectangle. I am getting a perfectly segmented image if I choose **watershed** instead of **meanshift** in **segmentation algorithm**. Any suggestions ?